# Make embed element mobile responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a [site](https://milan1.nl/contact.html) with an embed element:

```
<embed src="https://cf.milan1.nl/" style="width:294px; height: 109px;">
```

The problem is, on mobile screen the element is tiny, no matter what I tried.

Comment: please share what exactly have you tried and on what device (OS, screen resolution) in what browser (+version) do you see the element of which size (and what size is expected). Otherwise, it's hard to say, what exactly the problem is. Please also do your best at providing a [mcve] (usually creating one and writing a good question helps with solving the problem by itself)

Comment: when building [mcve], please also check whether the issue is specific to the `embed` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the initial scale of page on mobile devices so the page fit the mobile resolution. Try this in the header of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```